# pandas Integers to negative integer powers are not allowed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df`,

```
decimal_places    amount
 2                10
 3                100
 1                1000
```

I want to create a new column `converted_amount` based on the following calculation:

```
df = (df.assign(
        converted_amount=lambda x: x.amount * 10 ** (2 - x.decimal_places.fillna(2, downcast='infer'))))
```

but I got the following error,

```
ValueError: Integers to negative integer powers are not allowed.
```

I am wondering how to get around this, so the result will look like,

```
decimal_places    amount    converted_amount
   2                10           10
   3                100          10
   1                1000         10000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here. Firstly as the error suggests, the values must be floats. But secondly, by setting `downcast='infer'`, the values in `decimal_places` are cast to integer as all decimal places are `0`, and hence you'll get the same error. So you want:

```
df = df.astype(float)
df = (df.assign(
      converted_amount=lambda x: x.amount * 10 ** (2 - x.decimal_places.fillna(2))))
```

---

For a faster approach you could work with the underlying numpy arrays:

```
df['converted_amount'] = df.amount.values*(10**(2-df.decimal_places.fillna(2).values))
```

---

```
print(df)
    decimal_places  amount  converted_amount
0             2.0    10.0              10.0
1             3.0   100.0              10.0
2             1.0  1000.0           10000.0
```